# Error handling for data.table::rbindlist() in R

Tags: r

I am using a package to lookup some taxonomic information from the World Registry of Marine Species (worms). The returns from the API are formatted as a large list with nested data frames. I'm trying to unpack the nested data frames into a single data table using data.table::rbindlist(), but I am running into an issue where the error the API returns for non-matches are not a data.frame, data.table or list. The non-match error is simply character string indicating that no match was found for that concept. I'm trying to figure out how to create a conditional loop or statement to process the data.frame returns separate from the character values in my list. I still need to be able to see which animal concepts are not found in the WoRMS database.

This is the script that produces the list with the mixed contents of nested data frames and character values. Perhaps it would be wise to save the errors messages to a separate data frame or array. Or maybe force the errors into a class type list

```
library(future)
library(furrr)
library(progressr)
library(worms)

tlu_Taxon<- data.frame("concept" = c("Abudefduf", "Abudefduf abdominalis", "Acanella dispar", "Acanella dispar cf", "Actiniaria", "Actiniaria banded", "Actiniaria pink", "Actiniaria orange", "Actinopyga obesa", "Acanthascus sp"))

plan(strategy = "multisession", workers = availableCores()*0.75) #tells computer to allot 3/4 (can be adjusted based on needs) of processor and prepare them for parallel processing

progressr::with_progress({ #function to allow progress of vector processing to be visualized in a progress bar
  p <- progressr::progressor(steps = length(tlu_Taxon$concept))
  
  WORMS_match <- future_map(tlu_Taxon$concept, function(x){#equivalent of purrr map
    p()
    try(worms::wormsbymatchnames(x, marine_only = FALSE) #%>% #try will record the error but it won't shut down the progress.
    )
  }, .options = furrr_options(seed = NULL))
})

plan("sequential") #going back to serial processing

names(WORMS_match) <- tlu_Taxon$concept
```

Below is the line of code that I'm working on to unpack the nested data frames. Ideally the concepts with no API returns are either included as an empty row with NA across the columns, or they are summarized in a separate data frame. Right now the test code will work if there are no character values in my list, but I don't know how to handle the different class types separately from the same list.

```
test_1 <- data.table::rbindlist(l = WORMS_match, idcol = "concept", use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

Right now the error I receive is:

```
Error in data.table::rbindlist(l = WORMS_match, idcol = "concept", use.names = TRUE,  : 
  Item 6 of input is not a data.frame, data.table or list
```